# Need to generate 5000 means in R

Tags: python, cpu-word

I have a standard deviation, mean, and sample size. I'm needing to create a loop that will generate 5000 sample means

How do I go about doing so?

Answer (score 1):

```
set.seed(123)
#Data
mean.val <- 2
sd.val <- 0.5
nsamples <- 5000
#Empty matrix
Mymat <- matrix(0,nrow = nsamples,ncol = nsamples)
#Fill
for(i in 1:nsamples)
{
  Mymat[,i]<-rnorm(nsamples,mean = mean.val,sd=sd.val)
}
#Compute values
vecupper <- apply(Mymat,2,function(x) mean(x)+2.66*sum(abs(diff(x)))/length(x))
veclow <- apply(Mymat,2,function(x) mean(x)-2.66*sum(abs(diff(x)))/length(x))
```

Comment: Ok that worked well, now if I wanted to compute the upper and lower limit of each sample from the 5000 I couldn't just use:  2s = mean(vecmean) + 2.66*sum(abs(diff(vecmean)))/length(vecmean) b/c it gives me only 1 single upper and lower limit

Comment: @WW93 Just a moment, do you want 5000 samples of 5000 values?

Comment: So I got the 5000 samples, I'm now being asked to compute the upper and lower limit of each of the individual 5000 samples

Comment: @WW93 I have added an update, Hoping that helps you!

Comment: you rock!!!!!!!

Comment: @WW93 Great! If this answer solved your issue consider accepting it https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work

Comment: @WW93 I have accepted your update, consider potentially accepting the answer if this helped!